# Bottom left corner's menu not showing

Tags: interface, bevel

[image]

Hi everyone, I found the setting menu is not showing up when I'm doing something like bevel or subdivide, normally there will be a menu setting bevel's edge at that rectangle, but now it's just never poping up.

Thank you!

Comment: For reference, that "setting menu" is called the _operator panel_ and I'm at a loss to explain why it's missing. For a workaround, you could try pressing F9 each time you do an action that you need to "adjust", but that's not an ideal solution by any means.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that you accidentally unchecked the *Adjust the Last Operation* option, which is why your operator menu is not seen.

If you have not unchecked this option then follow Christopherb NBennet`s solution which he posted in the comments section.

[image]

### Method

In *Object Mode*, click on the *View* button as shown in the GIF and then check the *Adjust the Last Operation* option.

Comment: That looks like it to me.

Comment: thanks Chris :)

Comment: That's correct, I did uncheck that option!! Thank you so much.

Comment: your welcome! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are currently running the operation. (as indicated by the dashed line toward your cursor.)

This menu only shows up when an action is completed and it is not visible when the action is in progress.

I would indeed like to see this menu when the action is in progress though, that would be handy. The right-click select forums are the place for feature discussions.